# bitwise OR unexpected result

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

This line of code:

```
console.log((90000000000000|0).toString());
```

output:

```
-1039687680  ( bin -111101111110000110000000000000 )
```

According to [32-bit signed integer conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_logical_operators), I expect:

```
/--discarded--\/---------significant----------\
10100011101101011000010000001111010000000000000    = 90000000000000
                              │
               11000010000001111010000000000000 OR
               00000000000000000000000000000000
               ================================
               11000010000001111010000000000000    = -1107795968
           sign/\------significant bits-------/
```

Why I obtain **-1039687680** instead of **-1107795968**?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in post you linked, it's in two's complement format.

negative 11000010000001111010000000000000 xor 1 plus 1 equals

positive 11110111111000011000000000000000, 1039687680

finally -1039687680 gained.